# Redux Store is cleared after every action

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm a beginner to Redux and having trouble.

Somehow after every action, my whole store is completely cleared and only current action is executed. I'm going to describe the situation with screenshot of action log.

Here is my action:

```
function writeProduct(id) {
    return {
        type: 'WRITE_PRODUCT',
        id
    }
}
```

Here is my reducer:

```
case 'WRITE_PRODUCT':
    console.log("WRITE PRODUCT ACTION: ", action);
    console.log("state: ",state);
    return {
        productID: action.id
    };
```

And here is the consoled log during the `dispatch` of `writeProduct` action.

https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2018/5/9/c4cfc7debab662dfe241889d86254cd1-full.png

What I do wrong? Why after every dispatch previous store is overwritten?

Comment: you should return your state rather than productID

Comment: If you're not using `combineReducers`, you'll need to handle merging properties.

Comment: If you have just one ruducer then overwriting the state will overwrite the store.

Comment: There is an excellent video series explaining how redux works. ["Redux: The Reducer Function"](https://egghead.io/lessons/react-redux-the-reducer-function) is where you should start for this particular issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're overwriting the previous state in your reducer.
You should include all the previous state and only change what the reducer should.

Eg.
In your reducer:

```
return {
    ...state,
    productID: action.id
};
```

Notice the `...state` part, which includes all the previous state in the result.

[I'd suggest you review the redux docs on immutable updates](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns)

Also, your action object isn't FSA compliant, should probably read about that too.

Comment: Thanks, man. I did not know that whole store is cleared after the action. It solved my problem.I surely need to read more about Redux. Now, I'm going to take a more detailed look to your suggested link and other documents. Have a good day.

Answer (score 1):

hmmm i don't know why the whole store is wiped out but

```
case 'WRITE_PRODUCT':
console.log("WRITE PRODUCT ACTION: ", action);
console.log("state: ",state);
return {
    productID: action.id
};
```

should be

```
case 'WRITE_PRODUCT':
 console.log("WRITE PRODUCT ACTION: ", action);
 console.log("state: ",state);
return {
    ...state,
    productID: action.id
};
```

```
`state` is passed to your reducer function